# Setup wordpress on VPN protected private IP

Tags: wordpress, ip, vpn

I finished developing a WordPress site and everything was going great.

Then came the time for migration to the private VPN protected IP of the client. After I migrated the site and set up the Website URL and Home to the domain name that people use to bypass the restriction on the Private IP. The website became available for normal users.

I then tried going to the backend and do some more changes to the site and I was surprised that the backend doesn't load, it loads the left panel but all the content of the backend pages doesn't load, so I end up with blank backend pages.

[image: Blank Backend]

The issue is that when I switch it back to having site URL and home URL to the VPN protected private IP in the wp_options database table, the backend works again but since the IP is protected, people cant see the website anymore.

Note that in both base URL settings, my VPN is on but when I put the private IP as base URL, it works and when I put the domain name that goes to the public Ip goes to the private IP, the frontend is good and people can see the website but the backend is blank.

Any idea what needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's loading some of the page before running into a PHP error that's hidden. Try changing the value of `WP_DEBUG` from `false` to `true` in wp-config.php and see if it gives you anymore information.

Comment: I tried that and I got the same error on both settings: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50556 Library:50637 in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
Both settings show the same warning but one works and the other doesnt